# Fluent NHibernate mapping Parent/Child Tables with orphaned child records

Tags: nhibernate, foreign-key-relationship, fluent, outer-join, orphan

I'm new to Fluent NHibernate and C#.NET and struggling with this problem.

I have two tables:

**audit**:
 audit_seq  (Primary Key),
 user_code  (Foreign Key),
 audit_date

**username**:
 user_code  (Primary Key),
 user_name

The audit table contains audit records with a foreign key field (user_code) for the user.  **The problem** is that some of the user records have been deleted, but the audit records for those users remain (so I have orphaned Foreign Keys in the audit table).  What I want is a result set with audit_seq, audit_date and user_name (but if orphaned the user_name should be blank).

I am using the following mapping, but believe that I need to change the UserName reference to create an outer join.  I am not sure how to do that.

```
public class AuditMap : ClassMap<Audit>
{
    public AuditMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.AuditSeq).Column("audit_seq").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.AuditDate).Column("audit_date");
        References(x => x.UserName).Column("user_code");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The table `username` should be mapped to an Entity (class `UserName`? I will use the `User` to distinguish its property `UserName`). Then it could be used in the *Audit* as a reference. In C#

```
public class Audit
{
  ...
  public virtual User User { get; set; }
  public virtual string UserName
  {
    get { return User != null ? User.UserName : string.Empty ;}
  }
}
```

The `User` mapping

```
public class UserMap : ClassMap<User>
{
    public UserMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.UserCode).Column("user_code").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.UserName).Column("user_name");
        ...
    }
}
```

Then we can adjust the `Audit` mapping this way:

```
public class AuditMap : ClassMap<Audit>
{
    public AuditMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.AuditSeq).Column("audit_seq").GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        Map(x => x.AuditDate).Column("audit_date");
        References(x => x.User).Column("user_code")
             .NotFound.Ignore();
    }
}
```

so now we have `Audit` having reference to `User`. It will ignore the fact that some referenced Users are missing (`.NotFound.Ignore()`). And if there is any, our `UserName` property will return its name.